# Andengine AnimatedSprite stops animating when onTimePassed hits to load the games resources (Splash/Loading Scene)

Tags: android, animation, screen, andengine, splash-screen

So I am creating a splash screen that in the background loads up the games resources.
During the splash screen their is an animated sprite that should sit in the center of the screen and animate until the resources are all loaded and I can simply just switch scenes to the menu scene.
However at the moment the sprite animates for a short amount of time then freezes and just sits doing nothing for a few seconds, then loads the menu scene (this "few seconds" changes duration depending on how quick the phone is that it is being run on, e.g. my phone (newish) is like a split second, however my friends phone (oldish) takes 4 or 5 seconds).

**I want to have the sprite animate for the entire time that we can see the splash screen, whilst the loading is happening in the background... Does that make sense?**

Below is my MainActivity class...

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity 
{
protected static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
protected static  int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;

protected PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
SceneManager sceneMan;
Camera camera;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() 
{
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    float camwid = CAMERA_WIDTH;
    float camhi = CAMERA_HEIGHT;

    CropResolutionPolicy pop = new CropResolutionPolicy(camwid,camhi);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, pop, camera);
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception 
{
    sceneMan = new SceneManager(this, mEngine, camera);
    sceneMan.loadSplashResources();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception 
{
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(sceneMan.createSplashScene());
}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception 
{
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) 
        {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            sceneMan.loadFirstTimeRunAllResources();
            sceneMan.createMenuScene();         
            sceneMan.setCurrentScene(AllScenes.MENU_SCREEN);
        }
    }));

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
}
```

And below is the create splash scene code that creates the stuff for my splash scene and tells the sprite to animate, this is located in another class that handles the loading and creating of the scenes...

```
public Scene createSplashScene()
{
    //Will only call once!
    //Will never return to this scene
    splashScene = new Scene();
    splashScene.setBackground(new Background(0,0,0));
    AnimatedSprite icon = new AnimatedSprite(0, 0, splashAniTR, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    icon.setPosition(camera.getWidth()-(camera.getWidth()/2)-(icon.getWidth()/2)+12,camera.getHeight()-(camera.getHeight()/2)-icon.getHeight()/2);
    icon.animate(300);
    splashScene.attachChild(icon);
    return splashScene;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

load all your game resources in onCreateResources()

```
this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sceneMan.loadFirstTimeRunAllResources();    
            }
        });
```

Comment: We have  to load all the resources while  the splash is running on device.

Comment: So I should insert this section of code into onCreateResources, before or after I load and create my splash screen?
Does it run on another thread?

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP , But...

Now there is the splash screen straight from the word go, but it isnt animated... :/
I think its very close to what I want but I want the loading to happen as the splash screen is sitting there being animated for aslong as it needs to for the loading to have finished

Comment: just add this code in your  onCreateResources(), place your splash resources as it is.If the resources taking more time, its better to increase time for timehandler in onPopulateScene.